# Handling emojis as user input

Tags: solidity, etherscan, polygon, encoding

I have a simple ERC721 [from OpenZeppelin](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol) solidity smart contract that I modified so people can include a small message in their token that is stored as a string.

When I mint from etherscan/polygonscan with the heart emoji (❤️) and read it back on etherscan it shows up as the pause button (⏸️).

Does anyone know why this would happen? The same thing happens with other emojis or certain characters like Chinese characters. Everything just gets jumbled.

Is there some special way you need to handle user input on the smart contract side?

Comment: Can you share an example contract with the issue? If the problem is with etherscan/polygonscan webpage then you should contact Etherscan support, since that page is closed source. It seems likely an encoding issue, try a different browser/operating system.

Comment: Yeah after digging into some of the frontend code of polygonscan it seems like maybe an encoding issue on their side. I will try to put together an example and post an isolated example here too if I have some time.